# necessary and sufficient conditions for the following inequality to be hold

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $p=(p_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers with $p_0>0$ s.t

$P_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n}p_k \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and let $t\in(0,1)$.

find necessary and sufficient conditions for the following inequality to be hold

$\displaystyle  \left|   k \frac{p_k}{P_{k-1}}- (k+1)\frac{p_{k+1}}{P_{k}}t \right| \leq C k (1-t)$   (C:constant)